# Redux: How to test a connected component?

Tags: unit-testing, reactjs, redux, enzyme

I am using `Enzyme` to unit test my React components. I understand that in order to test the raw unconnected component I'd have to just export it and test it (I've done that). I have managed to write a test for the connected component but I am really not sure if this's the right way and also what exactly would I want to test for the connected component.

**Container.jsx**

```
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import Login from './Login.jsx';
import * as loginActions from './login.actions';

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  auth: state.auth
});
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  loginUser: credentials => dispatch(loginActions.loginUser(credentials))

});
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Login);
```

**Container.test.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import {Provider} from 'react-redux';
import {mount, shallow} from 'enzyme';
import {expect} from 'chai';
import LoginContainer from '../../src/login/login.container';
import Login from '../../src/login/Login';


describe('Container Login', () => {
  it('should render the container component', () => {
    const storeFake = state => ({
      default: () => {
      },
      subscribe: () => {
      },
      dispatch: () => {
      },
      getState: () => ({ ...state })
    });
    const store = storeFake({
      auth: {
        sport: 'BASKETBALL'
      }
    });

    const wrapper = mount(
      <Provider store={store}>
        <LoginContainer />
      </Provider>
    );

    expect(wrapper.find(LoginContainer).length).to.equal(1);
    const container = wrapper.find(LoginContainer);
    expect(container.find(Login).length).to.equal(1);
    expect(container.find(Login).props().auth).to.eql({ sport: 'BASKETBALL' });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This is an interesting question.

I usually do import both container and component to do the testing. For container testing I use, `redux-mock-store`. Component testing is for testing async functions. For instance in your case, login process is an async function using `sinon` stubs. Here is a snippet of the same,

```js
import React from 'react';
import {Provider} from 'react-redux';
import {mount, shallow} from 'enzyme';
import {expect} from 'chai';
import LoginContainer from '../../src/login/login.container';
import Login from '../../src/login/Login';
import configureMockStore from 'redux-mock-store';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import { stub } from 'sinon';

const mockStore = configureMockStore([thunk]);

describe('Container Login', () => {
  let store;
  beforeEach(() => {
    store = mockStore({
      auth: {
        sport: 'BASKETBALL',
      },
    });
  });
  it('should render the container component', () => {
    const wrapper = mount(
      <Provider store={store}>
        <LoginContainer />
      </Provider>
    );

    expect(wrapper.find(LoginContainer).length).to.equal(1);
    const container = wrapper.find(LoginContainer);
    expect(container.find(Login).length).to.equal(1);
    expect(container.find(Login).props().auth).to.eql({ sport: 'BASKETBALL' });
  });

  it('should perform login', () => {
    const loginStub = stub().withArgs({
      username: 'abcd',
      password: '1234',
    });
    const wrapper = mount(<Login
      loginUser={loginStub}
    />);
  wrapper.find('button').simulate('click');
  expect(loginStub.callCount).to.equal(1);
  });
});
```

Comment: Would that suffice the tests for mapStateToProps and mapDispatch?

Comment: Yes indeed.. You must check with a coverage tool, u ll find it is fully covered

Comment: The actual thing I want to know is basically WHAT to test when we are going to test the container/smart component?

Comment: Have you done integration testing? I've been doing the unit testing but I've read around that we should write integration tests as well. If yes, I've got an important question that I can share the link

Comment: And by integration testing I mean triggering the action and asserting on the store update

Comment: Not exactly I basically mount the component and simulate events and assert it.. But may be this can give u a better idea https://skillsmatter.com/skillscasts/8029-integration-testing-strategies-for-react-applications

Comment: Thanks a million. Have you worked with 'nock' for API calls?

Comment: yes, but I prefer moxios and sinon.. one reason is i use axios for network calls

Comment: I'm using axios as well. I've actually never heard about moxios. Is that any better?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121213/discussion-between-umair-and-anoop).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39007954/react-redux-how-to-write-an-integration-test

Comment: And this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39008033/redux-nock-not-triggering-dispatch-on-success

Comment: when I try to mount with provider, I get "Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined."

Comment: can you show us your actual Container Component implementation?

Comment: @PositiveGuy I think the component is not exported correctly

Answer (score 4):

As you pointed out, the way I usually do this is to export the un-connected component as well, and test that.

i.e.

```
export {Login};
```

Here's an example. [Source of the component](https://github.com/jmeas/moolah/blob/de47546e05503967c1338f65788ff34294e6b669/client-src/categories/components/content/index.js#L11), and [source of the tests](https://github.com/jmeas/moolah/blob/de47546e05503967c1338f65788ff34294e6b669/test/unit/client/categories/components/content.js).

For the wrapped component, I don't author tests for those because my mappings (`mapStateToProps` and `mapDispatchToProps`) are generally very simple. If I wanted to test a wrapped component, I'd really just be testing those maps. So those are what I would choose to explicitly test, rather than re-testing the entire component in a wrapped form.

There are two ways to test those functions. One way would be to export the functions within the module itself.

i.e.;

`export {mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps}`

I'm not a huge fan of this, because I wouldn't want other modules in the app to access them. In my tests, I sometimes use [babel-plugin-rewire](https://github.com/speedskater/babel-plugin-rewire) to access "in-scope" variables, so that's what I would do in this situation.

That might look something like:

```
import {
  Login, __Rewire__
}

const mapStateToProps = __Rewire__.__get__('mapStateToProps');

describe('mapStateToProps', () => { ... });
```

Comment: I've done that. `import Login from ../login` is the un-connected component. The reason I haven't used {Login} is because they lie in separate files.

Comment: Also, what exactly do I need to test for the container component?

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean. So far I haven't tested those tbqh. If I did test them, I would use something like `babel-plugin-rewire` and test `mapStateToProps` and `mapDispatchToProps` rather than the wrapped component itself.

Comment: `mapStateToProps` and `mapDispatchToProps` how? Can you provide an example please?

Comment: Also, have you done the integration testing? I've been able to perform that but I have some async actions that return functions. Any idea how I can test them? I can create a separate question for it.

Comment: Updated the answer @umair. Let me know if that helps.

Comment: I wouldn't want to use `babel-plugin-rewire` tbh. And I am not really sure what you meant in the first option.

Comment: Your mapping functions are just variables, so you can export them from the module. Then, you can import them in your test to access them. In the same way that you're doing `export {Login}` and then `import {Login}` in your test, you could do `export {Login, mapStateToProps}` and `import {Login, mapStateToProps}`.

Comment: I personally have been following the pattern of exporting `mapStateToProps`, `mapDispatchToProps`, and `mergeProps` for the sake of testing them.  I had no idea that `babel-plugin-rewire` was an option - I'll have to try this out some time.

Answer (score 0):

If we have a router issue, we can consider to add the router lib into the test file, eg:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom';
import { mount } from 'enzyme';
import ReadDots from './ReadDots';

const storeFake = state => ({
  default: () => {
  },
  subscribe: () => {
  },
  dispatch: () => {
  },
  getState: () => ({ ...state })
});

const store = storeFake({
  dot: {
    dots: [
      {
        id: '1',
        dot: 'test data',
        cost: '100',
        tag: 'pocket money'
      }
    ]
  }
});

describe('<ReadDots />', () => {
  it('should render ReadDots component', () => {
    const component = mount(
      <Provider store={store}>
        <Router>
          <ReadDots />
        </Router>
      </Provider>
    );
    expect(component.length).toEqual(1);
  });
});
```