# React-redux: How to write an integration test

Tags: unit-testing, reactjs, integration-testing, redux

I am using `Enzyme` to test my react and redux portions. I've read around and have found that its a good practice to write an integration test for the component as well. 
So, that's simple as I have to call the action creators and check their updated values against store but I have some async actions that return `dispatch` actions.

**login.actions.js**

```
export function loginUser(credentials) {
  return dispatch => {
    dispatch(action.loginRequest());
    return axios({
      method: 'post',
      url: `${api}/login`,
      data: {
        email: _.trim(_.get(credentials, 'email')),
        password: _.get(credentials, 'password')
      }
    })
      .then(response => {
        const { data } = response;

        if (_.isEqual(_.get(response, 'status'), 200)) {
          dispatch(action.loginSuccess(data));
        }
      })
      .catch(err => {
        dispatch(action.loginError(err));
      });
  };
}
```

**login.actionCreators.js**

```
export function loginRequest() {
  return {
    type: types.LOGIN_REQUEST
  };
}
export function loginSuccess(payload) {
  return {
    type: types.LOGIN_SUCCESS,
    payload
  };
}
export function loginError(payload) {
  let error;
  switch (_.get(payload, 'response.status')) {
    case 422: {
      error = 'Invalid Credentials';
      break;
    }
    case 401: {
      error = 'Invalid user';
      break;
    }
    case 403: {
      error = 'Account not confirmed';
      break;
    }
    default:
      error = 'Something went wrong';
  }
  return {
    type: types.LOGIN_ERROR,
    error
  };
}
```

So, in order to perform a complete integration test, I would have to test the `login.actions.js` as well but since dispatch normally returns plain objects, in my case they are returning a dispatch function. How do I test them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is simple to test async actions.

I am using `moxios` ans `sinon`. You can basically extend this to all different cases and test it in the same pattern

```
import moxios from 'moxios';
import configureMockStore from 'redux-mock-store';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import { spy } from 'sinon';

const middlewares = [thunk];
const mockStore = configureMockStore(middlewares);

describe('async actions', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    moxios.install();
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    moxios.uninstall();
  });
  it(`should create action LOGIN_SUCCESS after successful login`, () => {
    moxios.wait(() => {
      const request = moxios.requests.mostRecent();
      request.respondWith({
        status: 200,
        response: { message: 'success', status: '200' },
      });
    });
    const expectedActions = [
      { type: types.LOGIN_REQUEST },
      { type: types.LOGIN_SUCCESS, data: { message: 'success', status: '200' } },
    ];
    const store = mockStore({ auth: {} });
    return store.dispatch(loginUser('abcd', '1234'))
    .then(() => {
      expect(store.getActions()).to.eql(expectedActions);
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: What if following the same scenario, I've to test if the state in the store updated or not?

Comment: You are testing with the store here, see the `mockstore` used here

Comment: Thanks a lot man! This is really a clear and top notch solution.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39008033/redux-nock-not-triggering-dispatch-on-success That's quite similar but what am I doing wrong in this?